# How to find the path of the keytool generated keystore (self generated)

Tags: java, security, alias, keystore, keytool

I created a keystore with the name `keys` using terminal

```
keytool -genkey -alias demo -keyalg RSA –keysize 2048 -keystore keys
```

I want to load this keystore in my java code:

```
ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;

try {
    fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("keys");
    ks.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

I don't know the path to my keystore 'keys'.
The only verified path I know is of the trusted keystore

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

which I don't think has my alias demo. How do I load my keysore in the code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found my all the self-generated keystores in my home folder or the directory in which I was working

/path to my working directory/***keystore_name***

/home/user name/***keystore_name***